# Joining customer id's based off the results of a previous join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an example of a BigQuery table where I know all the ID's equate to one unique user. However, I'm struggling to write any code to ensure I include all of these ID's. This is an example of a user `(ID1 = A)`. We can see that through joining multiple columns they all link back to the same original user.

| Row | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | D | H |
| 2 | A | D | I |
| 3 | B | D | J |
| 4 | B | D | K |
| 5 | B | D | M |
| 6 | B | E | M |
| 7 | B | E | M |
| 8 | C | E | M |
| 9 | C | F | N |
| 10 | C | F | O |

Initially I created some code that joined the datasets together (below)

```
WITH 
Q1 as (
SELECT 'A' AS ID1, 'D' AS ID2, 'H' AS ID3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'D', 'I' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'J' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'K' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'F', 'N' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'F', 'O'),

Q2 as (SELECT Y.ID1, Y.ID2, Y.ID3 FROM Q1 AS X
LEFT JOIN Q1 AS Y
USING (ID1)
WHERE ID1 = 'A'
GROUP BY 1,2,3),

Q3 AS (SELECT Y.ID1, Y.ID2, Y.ID3 FROM Q2 AS X
LEFT JOIN Q1 AS Y
USING (ID2)
GROUP BY 1,2,3),

Q4 AS (SELECT Y.ID1, Y.ID2, Y.ID3 FROM Q3 AS X
LEFT JOIN Q1 AS Y
USING (ID3)
GROUP BY 1,2,3)

SELECT * FROM Q4
```

This resulted in the table below but we can see that there are 3 missing rows of ID's.

| Row | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | D | H |
| 2 | A | D | I |
| 3 | B | D | J |
| 4 | B | D | K |
| 5 | B | D | M |
| 6 | B | E | M |
| 7 | B | E | M |
| 8 | C | E | M |

I think need to loop back through each iteration to make sure I haven't missed any possible values. I've had a look at BigQuery's new recursive CTE's but I can't get that to work. An example below attempting to find each ID1 related to 'A'

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
Q1 as (
SELECT 'A' AS ID1, 'D' AS ID2, 'H' AS ID3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'D', 'I' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'J' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'K' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'L' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'G', 'N' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'G', 'O'),

Q2 AS (

SELECT ID2 FROM Q1 WHERE ID1 = 'A'

UNION ALL 

SELECT Q1.ID1 FROM Q1 JOIN Q2 USING(ID2)
)

SELECT * FROM Q2
group by 1
order by 1 asc
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi LendenJ, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider below approach to get all the rows as per your requirement.

```
WITH 
Q1 as (
SELECT 'A' AS ID1, 'D' AS ID2, 'H' AS ID3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'D', 'I' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'J' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'K' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'F', 'N' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'F', 'O')

select a.*
 from Q1 a
 join ( select ID1, ID2,ID3
          from Q1
         group by ID1, ID2,ID3
        having count(*) > 0 ) b
   on a.ID1 = b.ID1
   and a.ID2 = b.ID2
   and a.ID3 = b.ID3
   order by a.ID1
```

**Output:**

[image]

And to find each ID1 related to 'A', you can consider below approach as you have written query for Q2.

```
WITH 
Q1 as (
SELECT 'A' AS ID1, 'D' AS ID2, 'H' AS ID3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'D', 'I' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'J' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'K' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'D', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'E', 'M' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'F', 'N' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'F', 'O'),

Q2 as (SELECT Y.ID1, Y.ID2, Y.ID3 FROM Q1 AS X
LEFT JOIN Q1 AS Y
USING (ID1)
WHERE ID1 = 'A'
GROUP BY 1,2,3)

select * from Q2
```

**Output:**

[image]